# How to extract fixed-effect estimates from fixest::feols() model?

Tags: r, fixest

The documentation of the `feols()` function in the `fixest` package provides the following usage example:

```
library(fixest)
res = feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, iris)
summary(res)
```

Which gives this result:

```
OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: Sepal.Length
Observations: 150 
Fixed-effects: Species: 3
Standard-errors: Clustered (Species) 
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Sepal.Width  0.432217   0.161308 2.67945 0.115623    
Petal.Length 0.775629   0.126546 6.12925 0.025601 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
RMSE: 0.305129     Adj. R2: 0.859538
                 Within R2: 0.641507
```

I can also see the information above for each covariate using `res$coeftable`:

```
              Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
Sepal.Width  0.4322172 0.08138982  5.310458 4.025982e-07
Petal.Length 0.7756295 0.06424566 12.072869 1.151112e-23
```

My question is, how do I get the estimate, SE, t values and p values for the fixed-effects? In this case, I want to see this information for "setosa", "versicolor", "virginica" of the variable "Species". I read the function documentation and poked around a bit in the `res` object, but could not find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Call `str(res)` to see what the underlying structure is. I don't have `fixest` installed, but sometimes it's something like `res$coefficients` (or just `coef(res)`).

Comment: I have already tried both and could not find what I am looking for, unfortunately

Comment: Are you looking for `fixef(res)`? I'm not sure that it makes sense to have SE, t values or p values for fixed effects. If you want that, just use `+`  instead of `|` in your formula.

Comment: Nice, this does indeed extract the estimates! Is there any way to get the p values as well?

Comment: But that's my point, it doesn't make sense to have a p value for the fixed effects here. The p values in the `coeftable` tell you the probability of seeing these coefficients by chance if the true coefficient was 0, given the fixed effect of `Species`, If you are looking for estimates with p values and se for `Species` then you are not really treating it as a fixed effect. If you really want estimates with p values for `Species` then they are just those that you would get with `feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Species, iris)`.

Comment: You should probably seek statistical help at [stats.se] to make sure you properly interpret these results.

Comment: @AllanCameron I see, thanks for the pointer. It is computationally and time-wise a bit expensive to rerun all models using this adapted formula, but if this is what it takes then I'll do it. Originally we were not planning on homing in on the fixed effects of course, but our client showed great interest in the effect of those categorical variables. Just to clarify: the estimates I will get with `$coeftable` for `Species` using `feols(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Species, iris)` will be the same as the ones I retrieved using `fixef(res)` on the original model?

Comment: @degeso no, because `setosa` is used for the intercept. `feols(Sepal.Length ~ 0 + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Species, iris)`  would give you the same result as `fixef` but the p values would represent the probability of seeing coefficients this extreme if their true value were 0. I don't know what you want the p value to show.